# Binary star system i need help finding habitable zone

Tags: space, worldbuilding-process, stars, solar-system

I have revamped my queshton a 3th time so i can get my ansure. The last 2 times i forgot something or got my math wrong. so i hope i got it all and got my math right, third times a charm. I have a binary star system i have imagined and i want to know the habitable zone. The system consists of 2 stars, one a star like are sun, other a red dwarf. As well as an earth like planet. The planit is 1.25* the size of earth. I want to know what i said earlier. Here’s some more in-depth info and a illustration.

Red star:

Mass: 716,040,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000kg

Radius: 139140000m

Red dwarf

Yellow star:

Mass: 1.989E+30kg

Radius: 785035685m

Star like are sun

Distance between 2 stars: 17,952,000,000m

Green planet:

Mass: 7,465,000,000,000,000,000,000,000kg

Radius: 7972625m

I plan on reposting to add 2 moons to this planit to have help with that, for now i want the system to work.
Earth like planet

[image]

Comment: What is the diameter of the green planets orbit and are the orbits of the planet and stars circular or nearly circular?

Comment: Near circular and diameter is radius times 2 but the orbit is detrmend by the habitable zone, one thing a asked for.

Comment: Downvoters: downvotes without comments are unhelpful. @Vexxen one reason that you're likely getting downvotes is that you don't have a clear question that can obviously have right answers... "_Whatever you can give_" is not a very good criterion. Pick something specific, ask that. Rewriting your question to ask where the habitable zone might be would be one way to do this.

Comment: I honestly don't get what is the difference between the 3 version of the question you posted, and I am tempted of closing 2 of them as duplicate and tell you to use the edit function instead of abusing the posts.

Comment: Ok the difference is that i took the advice and changed and redid my math. I will add duplicate to my last 2 questions.

Comment: I’ve looked at habitatable zones before, bare with me...

Comment: http://astro.twam.info/hz/ This is what I usually use.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Hopefully I’ve posted this image correctly, it basically refers to stellar zones and temperatures that allow carbon based life as we understand it to develop.

Obviously there’s a lot more too it than what this image displays. You’ll need to know (invent) accurate properties of the stellar structure.

Comment: I should also say that many of books I’ve read on theoretical astrobiology abhor terms such as ‘Goldilocks’ planets and insist that many biologists are very narrow minded.